# Finding range of a given function

Tags: functions

How do we find the range of

> $f(x)= \dfrac{\left(1+x+x^2\right)^{\!2}}{1+x^2+x^4}?$

Please explain step-by-step.

---

What I have tried

$$f(x)=y$$
$$y (1+x^2+x^4) = 1+2x+2x^2+x^2+2x^3+x^4$$
$$(y-1)x^4-2x^3+(y-3)x^2+2x+1=0$$
This is a fourth degree polynomial.and maybe we must invoke a condition such that x is real.

Comment: You need to show your work, or this question will be closed.

Comment: i donno how to type math symbols what to do, moreover, I have no idea.

Comment: When you signed up, there was a page to go to learn the easy directions to type mathematics correctly in this site

Comment: You say you have no idea, but [I don't believe you](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933). You know what range means, I presume. You can hopefully solve simpler, similar exercises. What would you do in those cases? Why didn't that work this time?

Comment: I tried putting it equal to y and cross multiplied but I got a 4th degree equation. If it was a quadratic equation I could have invoked discriminant greater than 0.

Comment: Thanks for the edit

Comment: @Suneetha Bhaskara: Are you in a Calculus course, or a course that assumes Calculus as a prerequisite?

Comment: I am studying in 12th class in India. JEE Advanced Preparation.

Comment: @Suneetha Bhaskara: So do you know how to find $dy/dx$?

Comment: yes of course! I know it

Comment: @Suneetha Bhaskara: The posted answers should be helpful. Also, if graphing calculators are allowed, you can get an instant sense of the global behavior of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that $\;1+x^2+x^4=(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1)\;$ , so your function is just

$$f(x)=\frac{x^2+x+1}{x^2-x+1}=1-\frac{2x}{x^2-x+1}\implies$$

$$f'(x)=-\frac{2x^2-2x+2-4x^2+2x}{(x^2-x+1)^2}=-\frac{-2x^2+2}{(x^2-x+1)^2}=\ldots$$

It's now easy to check extreme points, and taking into consideration that the function's always positive...

Comment: @Kitter Catter: Without seeing your comment, I used the idea you suggested in my posted answer.

Comment: Note that $f(x)=f(\frac 1x)$ so you can restrict your study on $[-1,1]$ and then $f'(x)=\frac{-2(1-x^2)}{(\cdots)^2}\le 0$. You get the rest by "symmetry". (ok $x\mapsto \frac1x$ is not exactly speaking a symmetry but you get the idea). For instance $f(0)=1$ is also the limit at infinity so you get asymptotic behaviour almost for free, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Taking advantage of DonAntonio's observation, we have
\begin{align*}
y&=\frac{(1+x+x^2)^2}{1+x^2+x^4}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{(x^2+x+1)^2}{(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1)}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{x^2+x+1}{x^2-x+1}\\[6pt]
\end{align*}
But now, as an alternative to finding derivatives, you can use the approach as in your attempt . . .

Cross-multiplying yields
$$(y-1)x^2-(y+1)x+(y-1)=0$$
hence we get a real solution for $x$ if and only if either $y=1$, or else, if $y\ne 1$, the discriminant 
$$D=(y+1)^2-4(y-1)^2=(3y-1)(3-y)$$
is nonnegative.

From there, we quickly get that the range for $y$ is $[\frac{1}{3},3]$.

**Update:**

After posting my answer, I noticed Kitter Catter's comment which outlines the same approach.

Answer (score 1):

Let me help you, but it will be you the one who finishes the work.

If we expand the numerator we observe that it is a degree-four polynomial in the form $x^4 + g_3(x)$, with $g_3$ a polynomial of degree three.

Thus, this function will go to $1$ both as $x$ goes to $+\infty$ and $-\infty$. This is relevant.

Look at the denominator. Where does it vanish? Nowhere, since there is no real number $x$ such that $1+x^2 + x^4$. This means that the function $f$ is continuous in all of the real line $\mathbb R$. Look at the previous paragraph: we have a continuous function, and it converges to a constant, a bounded real number as $x$ goes away from the origin. What do we take from this? Simply put, that this never goes to infinity. It will be bounded both by above and below.

So we know so far that $f$ tends to $1$ on either side. All what is left for you is to calculate $f$'s maximum and minimum on the real line. Since $f$ is continuous, $f$ shall attain each and every single value between the minimum and the maximum.

Do you know how to come up with the minimum and the maximum?

Answer (score 1):

For $x>0$  by AM-GM we obtain:
$$f(x)=\frac{(x^2+x+1)^2}{1+2x^2+x^4-x^2}=\frac{1+x+x^2}{1-x+x^2}=1+\frac{2x}{1-x+x^2}=$$
$$=1+\frac{2}{x+\frac{1}{x}-1}\leq1+\frac{2}{2-1}=3.$$
The equality occurs for $x=1$.

For $x<0$  by AM-GM again:
$$f(x)=1+\frac{2}{x+\frac{1}{x}-1}\geq1+\frac{2}{-2-1}=\frac{1}{3}.$$
The equality occurs for $x=-1$.

Also,  $f(0)=1\in\left[\frac{1}{3},3\right].$

Id est, since $f$ is a continuous function, we got the answer:
$$\left[\frac{1}{3},3\right].$$